# Font Awesome: how to remove the space around a circled number

Tags: font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome to create a circle around a number. HTML is as follows:

```
<span class="fa fa-stack fa-3x" >
            <i class="fa fa-circle-thin fa-stack-1x" ></i>
            <strong class="fa-stack-1x" >2</strong>
 </span>
```

Here is the jsfiddle demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/dkgzLrLf/2/

As seen in this demo, there is quite space around the circle. How can I remove it elegantly? And position it in the upper left-corner of its container (the div tag)?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't see why bother with Font Awesome since you only want a border around a number,
so here is a simple css solution

HTML:

```
<strong class="nbr">2</strong>
```

CSS:

```
.nbr {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    width: 1.2em;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Keep the line-height value same as the width (em or px), to have a perfect circle

Here is the updated Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dkgzLrLf/3/

Comment: I notice that if you change font size, then line-height/width rule is not working.

Comment: @curious1 "the line-height should be the same as the width" must have slipped
Tried it wit font-size from 10 to 150px, and line-height/width from 1 to 5em or 50px, still looks fine